# Given a BST, print all the possible combinations of differents nodes pairs

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-search-tree, combinations, permutation

Suppose you have the following BST:

```
  4
 /  \
2    8
```

Implemented using the following C struct:

```
typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
}node;
```

The output would be:

```
(4,2)
(4,8)
(2,4)
(2,8)
(8,4)
(8,2)
```

**How can this algorithm be implemented?**

And is it possible to implement the algorithm in such a way that gives the correct output in a runtime better than ***O(n^2 - n)*** ?

Comment: I don't think so. Because the number of the output pairs will be n^2 - n anyway.

Comment: You walk the tree.  At each node, you perform a second, independent traversal.  At each node of each nested traversal, output the pair formed by the current node of the first traversal and the current node of the nested traversal, unless they are the same node.  You can use either depth-first or breadth-first traversal; you get all pairs either way, but in (generally) different orders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to a solution:

> And is it possible to implement the algorithm in such a way that gives the correct output in a runtime better than O(n^2 - n) ?

No, it is not possible to have a runtime better than ***O(n^2 - n)***.

> How can this algorithm be implemented?

```
void printPairsHelper(node* root, node* temp){
    if (!root) return;
 
    if (root != temp) printf("%d, %d\n", root->data, temp->data);
 
    printPairsHelper(root->left, temp);
    printPairsHelper(root->right, temp);
}

void printPairs(node* root, node* curr){
    if (!curr) return;
 
    printPairsHelper(root, curr);
 
    printPairs(root, curr->left);
    printPairs(root, curr->right);
}
```

Usage:

```
//Declare the BST
node* root = NULL;

//Add some nodes to the BST

//...

//Call the function
printPairs(root, root);
```